# Google Domain and G-Suite with AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, cross-domain

I have been looking around the internet and I have come across a few different ways to link my AWS EC2 instance to my domain name. It looks like I could do it using Route 53 but I am not entirely sure on that process. The other way is to map it from google. These seem like the best instructions I have found for that: [link a Google Domain to Amazon ec2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467541/link-a-google-domain-to-amazon-ec2-server)

The question that I can not seem to find is what about my email address. I pay google so that I can have some email addresses `name@mydomain.com`. Now these work fine and I have had them up and running for months. But now I want to have my website (it is a web app) point to it. Because currently when you go to `mydomain.com` it says `This site can’t be reached mydomain.com’s server IP address could not be found.`

Some help here on how to do this would be great. I am afraid that I am going to set this up incorrectly and then lose access to my gmail account which I cannot have happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain's email is configured via `MX` DNS records. You would point your domain to your EC2 instance by adding `A` or `CNAME` DNS records. The two configurations are completely separate. You will not break your current email setup by adding an `A` or `CNAME` record that points to the EC2 instance. You simply need to add that record in your DNS settings, wherever your DNS is currently hosted. You don't need to make any changes in your Gmail account configuration, and you don't really need to use Route53 either (although it does add some nice features). You had to configure the `MX` records somewhere at some point, to setup your G-Suite account for your domain. You just need to go into that same DNS configuration (most likely still hosted at the company where you initially purchased the domain name) and add an additional record.

Comment: Great Answer! This is just what I needed to understand, worked perfectly.